# ajax call not getting the response from codeigniter controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to validate user login using jQuery and CodeIgniter. In case that user is found, he will  be redirected to another page, so what i am trying here is to get the error message when the user type wrong user name or password. That is my main objective.

Within the view, I have this code:

```
<?php
    $param = 'id="formLogin"';          
    echo form_open('backOffice/loginCheck', $param); 
?>
 <label for="username">* user name</label>
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />

 <label for="password">* password</label>
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

  <input type ="submit" name="login" id="login" value ="LOGIN" />
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>backOffice/js/loginscript.js"></script>
```

Now, here is the code from the loginscript.js

```
 btnLogin.on('click', function(errorMessage){
       if(userName.val()!='' &&  password.val() !=''){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'backOffice/loginCheck',
            data: 'formLogin.serialize()',
            success: function(errorMessage){
                console.log('i never get here');
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(errorMessage);

       } 
   })
```

And on the end, here is the code from the controller

```
 public function loginCheck()
    { 

       // set the validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|encode_php_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|encode_php_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><p class=jsdiserr>', '</p><br />');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) 
        {

            $ids=array();
            $ids[0]=$this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
            $ids[1] = $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
            $query = $this->backOfficeUsersModel->get();
            if($query)
                {
                    $data = array(
                    'username'       => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'isUserLoggedIn' => true
                    );    
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                $data['title'] = "Welcome to dashboard!";
                $data['main_content'] = 'dashboard';
                $this->load->vars($data);
                $this->load->view('backOffice/template');
        } else {   
            $errorMessage = "Wrong Username or Password";
            $this->cms(json_encode($errorMessage));
        }
        } else {

            // form validation fail, send the message
            // form validation to fail, mean that user has javascript disabled
            $errorMessage = "Wrong User Name OR Password.<br /> Please try again!";
           $this->cms(json_encode($errorMessage));
        }



    } // end of function loginCheck
```

Comment: Just change the dataType to `json`, not `jsonp` as that is for cross domain and only accepts GET requests.

Comment: I change it already...still getting undefined when trying to console.log the errorMesaage

Comment: What the function `cms` does? can you post that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `data: 'formLogin.serialize()',` should be `data: formLogin.serialize(),` that's if `formLogin` is a jQuery object congaing the form with the data you want to send. It looks like your data type should be `json` not `jsonp`

Also you have `errorMessage` as your event object but try to call `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: i removed the quotes from formLogin...nothing change. I still get undefined when I try to console.log the error message. I just place the success handler for debugging purposes...but I never reach that point for the moment. I am trying to use error message to get response from the controller.

Comment: Is `formLogin` a form element? if so try `data: $(formLogin).serialize(),`.

Comment: Above in the code, I have: formLogin = $('#formLogin')...it is declared as variable. I try $(formLogin).serialize() as well, still getting undefined when trying to console.log the error message.

Comment: Did you change `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: yes. same, still getting undefined when trying to console.log the errorMessage

Comment: @Zoran change `btnLogin.on('click', function(errorMessage){` to `btnLogin.on('click', function(e){`

Answer (score 0):

first thing you need to check is the ajax request showing any `error code` or `200` response.

second thing is `btnLogin.on('click', function(errorMessage){` looks wrong because here `errorMessage` might be acting as `event`.

third thing is in following code, `errorMessage` is used for success response as well. recommend you to change the variable name.

```
btnLogin.on('click', function(errorMessage){
       if(userName.val()!='' &&  password.val() !=''){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'backOffice/loginCheck',
            data: 'formLogin.serialize()',
            success: function(errorMessage){//here
                console.log('i never get here');
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(errorMessage);

       } 
   })
```

fourth thing is in `loginCheck()`, you are doing following things

```
$this->load->vars($data);
$this->load->view('backOffice/template'); // both link will echo the html part
```

and

```
$errorMessage = "Wrong Username or Password";
$this->cms(json_encode($errorMessage));// json encode works for php array, not for string
```

so according to me `loginCheck()` responding string instead of json.

lastly add `error` function in `ajax()` so that you may also see the error. for more information, [check this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)